# Manipulating pointers to arbitary locations

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I have a function that returns a word of data and I need to put it in a struct; however, when I manipulate any pointers, I'm not on the correct boundary.

It might be easier for me to show:

```
void grab_object(size_t copies, struct iovec *iov)
{


  union u {
    long val;
    char chars[WORD_SIZE];
  }data;

  iov = malloc(sizeof(struct iovec) * copies);

  size_t numWords = (sizeof(struct iovec) * copies) / WORD_SIZE;

  if(DEBUG)
  {
    printf("numWords %zx\n", numWords);
    printf("size of word %zx\n", WORD_SIZE);
  }

  size_t x = 0;
  for(x = 0; x < copies; x++)
  {
    size_t i = 0;
    struct iovec *laddr = iov;
    while(i <= numWords)
    {

        data.val = function()
        memcpy(laddr, data.chars, WORD_SIZE);
        laddr += WORD_SIZE;
        i++;
    }

    size_t remainder = size % (WORD_SIZE);
    if(remainder != 0)
    {
      data.val = function();
      memcpy(laddr, data.chars, remainder);
    }
  }
}
```

This copies data into the first element of struct; however, it doesn't on the second.

When I print the addresses of the elements and of laddr I get something similar to the following:

```
iov_len loc: 0x9a5148
starting laddr: 0x9a5140
after incrementing laddr: 0x9a5150
iov_len loc: 0x9a5148
starting laddr: 0x9a5150
after incrementing laddr: 0x9a5160
```

So why is laddr incrementing by 0x10 instead of by 1, and how would I copy "in between" data (`iov_len`)?

Comment: That code appears that it would recurse infinitely - it starts with `void function()`, and in the first line of the `for()` loop you have `_U.val = function();` - which calls `function()`, which starts another `for()` loop which calls `function()`.

Comment: You need to post a complete set of code that actually compiles. See [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @user3386109 updated

Comment: `laddr` is incrementing by `0x10`, which evidently is the `sizeof(struct iovec)`.

Comment: So many bugs in this incomplete code.  Where to start...?  Is the definition of 'boundary' in your description the address of the `iov->iov_len` member, and if so, why do you assume that `iov_len` is the first element in `iov`?  What does the function signature look like, and how do you expect it to be used?  Where does `size` come from?  Why the infinite loop at the bottom of the function?  Why increment `laddr` at the end of the loop to a (likely) non-valid location for another `struct iovec`?

Comment: @MichaelGaskill that was the point trying figure out why I wasn't incrementing by 1. I'm just going to close this question. I can take criticism, but instead I feel like I've had people come up with ways to tell me I can't program. This is why I hate coming to this site. It is so caustic that it wards people off. I already had to shut down Olaf on a previous question, so I suggest the site do some reflection and ponder on its own rules.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I've had less people try to help me than have berated me over my programming skills (or lack there of).

Comment: @SailorCire I wasn't trying to be caustic - I was looking for information back from you.  There were 5 legitimate questions in my comment.  I have a VERY long answer that I've spent the past 30 minutes composing to help you get what you needed.  It's simply difficult to figure out from your code and the description what was 'real' code, what was 'debug' code, and what you were really trying to get from it.  It wasn't an indictment of your programming skills - we all had to start somewhere.  I was trying to get information from you to be able to answer your question accurately and completely.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill Sorry you took the brunt of it; however, I've solved the problem below. I was getting a word (memory size) of data back from a function. That data was of type iov; however, since it is just a series of words it needs to be put back in place (memcopy). Since iov is contains multiple words, I need to make multiple calls to function(). The problem was, how do I put this new data into the right section of memory. When I tried to increment the address, C incremented it by sizeof(iov). I solved it by using a char and incrementing that by word size.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So as user31264 hinted at, `laddr` was incrementing by the size of `struct iovec`.

The simple solution is to use a data-type that evenly divides into the size of `struct iovec`. Luckily, the char will always be 1 byte. So:

```
char *laddr = (char *)iov;
```

to declare our container and

```
laddr += sizeof(long);
```

to increment by one word.

Comment: ...who downvoted my own answer? At least leave a comment as to why it isn't good.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *chars[sizeof(long)];
```

declares array of pointers to character.

You should write instead

```
char chars[sizeof(long)];
```

PS: the original author fixed this, but he has more problems with his code.

Comment: You're right and I have it that way in my code. I just didn't copy it correctly.

Comment: Make a code which works (except for the problem), and copy it with the mouse. Currently, in "struct *data = malloc(sizeof(struct));", sizeof(struct) make no sense, so the code won't even compile.  I have no idea how many more errors you did in copying.